# pytest installing : TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, installation, pytest

I am tying to install pytest by running the following command :

```
pip install pytest
```

in my shell. But I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm confused because I can import pytest (in a python code for example) and run its functionnality:

```
from pytest import *
```

and I don't get any errors.

Can you help me ?

PS : my final goal is to run

```
pytest --cov="file-name" --cov-report html test_*.py
```

as a command

Answer (score 0):

You just have to `import pytest` rather using `from pytest import *`

and `pytest -v -s relativepath` add the path to the file
or folder

Try to check what version of python you are having if python 3.x then use 
`python3 install pytest`

Comment: Several things :   `python3 install pytest` runs ok

Comment: But when i type `pytest -v -s relativepath` or even `pytest -- version` i get another error

Comment: `+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pytest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`